# ROC curve when the numbers of both total positives and negatives are unknown

Tags: roc, sensitivity-specificity

I have to use a roc curve to find an agreement between sensitivity between the FPR and TPR. The problem is that I only know the true positives. How could I circumvent this?
More accurate, I have a vector with some points known to be true, but I have no idea about the other points. How could I get a ROC curve?

Thanks

Comment: I am actually about to submit a manuscript to this year's ICML that address this exact problem. I will update you when it is available. In case you need an urgent fix, feel free to contact me directly. Essentially you only need a set of known positives and a rough estimate of how many positives you have in the unlabeled part of your test set to get very reliable estimates of the corresponding ROC curve.

Comment: Hi Marc,
Thanks for your answer. The problem is that I do not know that 'rough estimate' of the number of positives in the unlabeled part. However, I would like to hear more about your method, it sounds interesting to my project.

Comment: I'll update you in about one week (after submission).

Comment: Slightly later than I hoped, but here's the relevant paper [*Assessing binary classifiers using only positive and unlabeled data*](http://arxiv.org/abs/1504.06837).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can.  A ROC curve assumes that you have a binary classifier (the "ground truth" or "gold standard") and a predictor for each subject.  If you don't have the binary classifier then you cannot form the ROC curve at all.

You should look at your study and see if you can use a modified classifier.  For instance, I was doing an ROC analysis once for a test in the medical field.  On some subjects we had pathology as our classifier, but on others we used clinical follow-up.  I.e. if the suspected disease had not progressed at the 12 mo follow-up then we called it "negative" even though, in principle, they could have had very very slowly progressing disease.

Comment: It is possible, have a look at our recent paper [*Assessing binary classifiers using only positive and unlabeled data*](http://arxiv.org/abs/1504.06837).